# OpenCV Android initializing Mat crashing the application with unsatisfiedLinkedError

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, mixed

It seems like i am not able to use any of opencv variable or function it just crash with the following kind of error using only Mat outMat = new Mat(); this code when i am coding in java class.

```
Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown during Lorg/opencv/core/Mat

05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.ndkexample.FarhandkproActivity$1.onClick(FarhandkproActivity.java:60)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library opencv_java not found
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  at org.opencv.core.Mat.<clinit>(Mat.java:2065)
05-19 11:27:58.403: E/AndroidRuntime(890):  ... 12 more
```

I am using java ndk , ndk part successfully compile and gives the result even on the java. But when i call inside the java any of opencv function or variable it gives same kind of above error.

I have added the opencv java library externally , it compiles perfect without any error...

If i use library project by going in project properties->Android Then i have to add OpenCV 2.3 library project browsing the folder. Doing that Then it works fine and does not crash. But the size became like 14 MB and takes too much time to load. So instead of that i tried OpenCVAndroid jar file as an external library but using that gives me error.

Kindly help because i spent 2-3 hours but not able to solve it. I am not interested large size due to the library project addition.

Comment: Check if `opencv_java.so` is packaged into your apk.

Comment: yes it does not have this  , even though i have added the java library by project properties->java build path-> Add jars.  C:\AndroidOpencvSdk\OpenCV-2.3.1-android\OpenCV-2.3.1\bin\opencv-2.3.1.jars

Comment: am i missing something??

Comment: Add reference to Android library project instead of referencing separate jars.

Comment: using that it works but as i have mention in my post it make large size due to the complete library reference. and my application became like 15 MB while i was wondering if there is a way using just jars ??

Comment: It is so huge because it contains binaries for 3 architectures: `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a` and `x86`. If you are Ok with only one of them you can reduce the size approximately 3 times. Further reducing the apk size is a quite different question from your original one.

Comment: thanks for your answer also if you can reply here about how to reduce size i will appreciate this. Since i was previously wondering that it has something to do with jar files to reduce the size. But it crashed with unsatisfiedLinkedError...by the way i am using only Armbabi-v7a in my Application.mk